# Does moving the wagon after scoring stop you from taking the fairy?

Tags: carcassonne

So I've read the online [PDF rules](http://www.zmangames.com/uploads/4/7/1/7/47170931/carcassonne_new_edition.pdf) and can't seem to find an answer for this.

After scoring points in a round with the wagon, if you move the wagon to another unfinished city or road as per the wagon rules, does this count towards deploying a new follower and stop you from taking control of the fairy from the "Princess And The Dragon" expansion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Redeployment of the Wagon following scoring (at the end of a turn) [is a separate step](http://carcassonne.sciencegames.com) from the figure deployment step (for the next turn), so it has no effect on any of the actions you can take during the figure deployment step, including moving the Fairy.

Comment: This is pretty much what I figured, but the people that I have played with stated that the wagon "re-deploys" instead of "moving". And since the Fairy is changed owner at the end of turn, they would say that the fairy cannot go to someone who's wagon was "re-deployed".

Comment: @IronWilliamCash: Yes, it helps to stick with [consistent terminology](http://carcassonne.sciencegames.com).

Comment: Sorry if my terms aren't correct. I have most of the expansions in French, some in English and 2 in Dutch, so I might not have all the exact English terms since we play in French. But thanks, I'll try and impose terminology with a specific meaning.

Comment: @IronWilliamCash: No worries. I meant that it's common for people (even in "authoritative" rules references) to be lax about terms; and that's a common source of confusion.